# BV norm of a step function defined by another BV function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f\in BV(0,1)$, $g\in BV(1,2)$ and consider
\begin{equation}
h(x):=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{ for } x\in[0,1]\\ g(x) &\text{ for } x\in(1,2].
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
I guess that one would expect to have
\begin{equation}
\|h\|_{BV(0,2)} = \|f\|_{BV(0,1)}+\|g\|_{BV(1,2)}+|f(1)-g(1)|.
\end{equation}
But how does one really define the values $f(1)$ and $g(1)$, given that $f$ and $g$ are discontinuous? Namely, more generally, what is $\|h\|_{BV(0,2)}$ equal to?

Comment: Could you maybe say that each of $f,g$ are the difference of two monotone functions, and thus $f(1):=f(1^-)$ and $g(1):=g(1^+)$ are well-defined?

Comment: @Jose27 Thanks-would you mind just making precise why if $f$ is the difference of two monotonically increasing functions, then $f(1):=f(1^-)$ is well defined?

Comment: It depends on your definition of $BV(a,b)$, but if the increasing functions in the decomposition are bounded, then this follows from the fact that monotone functions always have one-sided limits.